# TensorFlow python tests failing

Tags: python, tensorflow

We are working on adding support for big-endian in TensorFlow.
After making changes for 'kLittleEndian' flag and adding support in few files, we are still facing 3 test failures(in TensorFlow v0.10.0 ), namely:
sparse_split_op_test, sparse_matmul_op_test, string_to_hash_bucket_op_test.

While debugging these tests by comparing the *op/ret* values on our system and x86(tests pass here), it was observed that the values are getting populated after   *[self._add_op(ret)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v0.10.0/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L2320)*  present in create_op function.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v0.10.0/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L2241

The [definition of *_add_op*](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v0.10.0/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L2023) includes *with self._lock:* which suggests it is thread safe.
Any pointers on how to debug further? Regarding which thread populates output values of the Tensor?

We are executing *bazel test //tensorflow/python/sparse_split_op_test* and debugging using pdb.

Comment: How can a value be populated when a op is added? Only when session is running, can a result be returned.

Comment: yes true, but while stepping through the code using pdb below was observed:   

         `set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)`  
-------> p  ret.outputs[0].eval() -> *** NotFoundError: NotFoundError()  

         `self._add_op(ret)`  
-------> p ret.outputs[0].eval() -> array([3, 5, 7])  
     
         `self._record_op_seen_by_control_dependencies(ret)`  
   
At this moment, multiple threads are seen running. couldn't understand how they are spawned and how values are populated.

Comment: Does anybody have any inputs regarding this issue? Some help would be greatly appreciated!